# BSOD's + fan is not working as well

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, bios, bsod, fan

I keep getting a BSOD, varies on when it hits. Here is the error:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
OS Version: 6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3
Locale ID: 1033
```

Additional information about the problem:

```
BCCode: 24
BCP1: 00000000001904AA
BCP2: FFFFFA6005BED2C8
BCP3: FFFFFA6005BECCA0
BCP4: FFFFF80002263B5D
OS Version: 6_0_6002
Service Pack: 2_0
Product: 768_1
```

Files that help describe the problem:

```
C:\Windows\Minidump\Mini120512-03.dmp
C:\Windows\Temp\WER-28735-0.sysdata.xml
C:\Windows\Temp\WER9F5A.tmp.version.txt
```

The fan attached to the motherboard is not working as well, any ideas? Faulty hardware?

Comment: Let me rephrase this. 1) Some of my fans are not working; my computer might not get cooled enough which can lead to a lot of problems. 2) I have problems. 3) Help?

Comment: Run a program to measure the temperature of your CPU.

Comment: sounds like a heat issue. Check your connections on your fans make sure they are all plugged in correctly

Comment: upload the file C:\Windows\Minidump\Mini120512-03.dmp so that we can look at it with WinDbg.

Answer (score 0):

A [Bug Check Code of 24 is a bug check for the "NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), meaning there was an error the NTFS.SYS driver couldn't handle.

It's indicative of a corrupted file system, or a failing hard drive or a failing hard drive controller.

The first step is to run a `chkdsk` (with no switches, so it runs in Read-Only mode) and see if it reports any problems.  If it does, make a backup of stuff you want to keep  (just in case) and then run a `chkdsk /r` to check, and attempt to fix, the entire file system and disk surface.

File system corruption often happens if the machine is not cleanly shut down, and *this* bug check may be the result of other problems that caused an unexpected shutdown initially (which corrupted the file system).

So since you say your fans aren't working (did they *ever* work right?) ensure your system isn't overheating, and that you don't have other hardware problems that could cause another unexpected shutdown, which in turn could cause disk corruption to happen again.